How to disable options button appearing when TextInput pressed, and just show the keyboard directly?
In react-native android, when I click on the keyboard, a button pops up with animation at the bottom of the screen, as shown on the ss:

And when I click, it shows these options, where I can manually press the showKeyboard button and then it shows the keyboard:

But I want only the keyboard appears when I focus the TextInput, not a bottom options button. How can I do this?

That does not look like a normal keyboard nor normal keyboard behavior, do you have a custom keyboard installed?

@tyczj Nope. I just have a prop there <TextInput keyboardType='email-address' /> and nothing more. Even if I remove this prop, this strange behaviour happens. This started happening after I updated all the libraries except react-native.
"react": "18.3.1",
"react-native": "0.73.6",

This is a new keyboard feature which is enabled by default in google pixel emulaters. To fix this you just need to this.


Go To setting by clicking on settings as shown in the image or use shortcut key Alt + I.

in Settings menu you will see an option called Write in Text Fields, as shown below.




Just disable it and your problem will be solved.



Then you will have a normal keyboard.



Is there a way to disable this by code? Or a way to show only the keyboard, and not any buttons when textInput pressed?

Its a system feature for pixel devices. Normally keyboard will pop up in other devices as well as pixel devices if you use standard keyboard
